# I am trying to give inputs in a form in parent component and want to display those inputs in child component, using @input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am trying to give inputs in a form in parent component. and i want those inputs to be displayed in child component using @input. How to do that?

loginform.html (parent):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="form">
        <h2 id="registration">Login Form</h2>
        <form (ngSubmit)="navToDisplayForm()" #f="ngForm">

            <div>
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." name="firstname"
                    [(ngModel)]='userModel.firstnamedetail' required>
                


                <label for="middlename">Midddle Name</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="middlename" placeholder="Your middlename.." name="middlename"
                    [(ngModel)]='userModel.middlenamedetail' required>
                
                <br>
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Your lastname.." name="lastname"
                    [(ngModel)]='userModel.lastnamedetail' required>
                


            </div>


            <br><br>

            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" routerLink="/userdata" (click)="navToDisplayForm()"
                value="Submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
            <p>Not Regestered? <span>Create Account</span></p>
        </form>


    </div>
    

</body>
<app-userdata [childData]="sendToChild"></app-userdata>


</html>
```

loginform.ts (parent):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loginform',
  templateUrl: './loginform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loginform.component.css']
})
export class LoginformComponent implements OnInit {

  userModel = {
    firstnamedetail: '',
    middlenamedetail: '',
    lastnamedetail: ''
  }
  

  sendToChild: any;


  constructor(
    private route: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    

  }


  navToDisplayForm() {
    this.sendToChild = this.userModel;
    
   //this.route.navigate(['/userdata'])
  }
}
```

userdata.ts (child):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdata',
  templateUrl: './userdata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdata.component.css']
})
export class UserdataComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  @Input() childData: any = {
    firstnameToDisplay: '',
    middlenameToDisplay: '',
    lastnameToDisplay: ''
  };


  ngOnInit(): void {


  }

  
}
```

userdata.html (child):

```
<div>
    <form class="display">
        
        <p>First Name: {{childData.firstnameToDisplay}}</p>
        <p> Middle Name: {{childData.middlenameToDisplay}}</p>
        <p>Last Name :{{childData.lastnameToDisplay}}</p>
        
        </div> -->
        
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clean up your code and remove unnecessary comments.

Comment: Just remove the `this.route.navigate(['/userdata'])` in `navToDisplayForm()`. This causes a page reload.

Comment: If you want to retain the data between router navigation, you need to either pass it trough the link or save it in a service or make a request to a backend and store it there.

Comment: @Jovana . Hi sorry about that., I just removed the comments..., I have followed Akash's suggestion in comments,, but its still not displaying data..

Comment: @Garuno , hi thank you for the suggestion.. i removed the navigate link, but still no data is displaying..

Comment: First: in a component we **not** include `<html>`, `<head>` nor `<body>` tags. Angular use the index.html and "replace" the `<app-root></app-root>` by the components. About your question:you has `this.sendToChild = this.userModel;` inside a function `navToDisplayForm()` and don't call to this function in anywhere. BTW, you can use directly:`<app-userdata [childData]="userModel"></app-userdata>`

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, can you please tell me how to call this function? I was thinking, once we use input decorator with "childdata" name, i thought it will be automatically display data.. because this "childdata" i have assigned in parent component html  here : <app-userdata></app-userdata>

Comment: @mohankumar, I put attention that the problem is when you asign **this.sendToChild**, of course automatically the input asign the value.

Comment: @Eliseo , exactly.. but still there's no data.. I am not getting the exact issue..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is you are actually binding wrong data you are sending data as firstnamedetail and trying to use that as firstnameToDisplay binding not work like this. You can update your binding in userData.ts with @Input() childData: any; and your userData.html with this snippet.

```html
<div>
  <form class="display">
    <p>First Name: {{ childData?.firstnamedetail ?? '' }}</p>
    <p>Middle Name: {{ childData?.middlenamedetail ?? '' }}</p>
    <p>Last Name :{{ childData?.lastnamedetail ?? '' }}</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here ?. is called optional chaining which will return undefined in case childData.property is undefined and in case of undefined ?? (Nullish coalescing operator) will show empty string.

Comment: Hi@Akash, thank you for the sugegstion.., its still empty in my child page,.. no data is coming.. I have made edits that you suggested..

Comment: I solved it myself/... I took ngIf condition for the form..and now its displaying